# Laravel not properly config on my Wamp server

Tags: laravel, wamp

I have installed Laravel 4.2.11 on Wamp server through Composer. I have created the alias using wamp's Apache option but the URL http://localhost/laraveldemo/ (I have created the laraveldemo as alias) shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

How I rectify this?

Comment: The thing I always have to do, when installing Laravel on Wamp is: Wamp -> Apache -> Apache modules -> Enable: rewrite_module

Comment: rewrite_module is enabled already.

Comment: Go to config/app.php and set debug to true, you'll get a more precise error message.

Comment: Yes, I found it. Open SSL was not previously enabled. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For further reference, when encountering a problem like this the first step to a solution is enabling the debug flag. That way you can often see a better error message.

This can be done through changing the flag located in app/config/app.php

```
'debug' => true
```

Should be set to true.